# Converting from SecKeyAlgorithm to CK_MECHANISM in iOS

Tags: ios, security, digital-signature, pkcs#11

I wanted to convert SecKeyAlgorithm of iOS Security framework while create digital signature to CK_MECHANISM type of PKCS11. Could you please help me with the mapping. Thanks in advance.